# Sharing Web Page HTML and CSS files that are locally linked

Tags: html, css, web-hosting

I want to show a website to my colleagues at work.
The file system looks like this...

```
home.html
about.html
products.html
logo.jpg
home_font.webfont
[stylesheets]
    home.css
    about.css
    products.css
```

Now, is it possible for me to upload these files online onto a central server whilst still keeping them linked relative to each other and still maintain functionality so my colleagues can test the page online by themselves?

Comment: You can simply serve the files through a locally installed server. Open port 80 on your machine, and your coworkers on the intranet should be able to access it. You might want to check out [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have referred to the files in relation to each other and not with specific URL paths.  For example, if there is an IMG tag in the home.html page that looks something like this:

```
<img src="logo.jpg"..../>
```

...you should be fine.  It's when you specifically try to reference paths to resources and then you change the server